# How to break comma separated values into <tr>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

#### JSON

```
{
  "catalog_name": ["Sistem Autodownline ", "Karipap Pusing Ayu"],
  "price": ["100", "8"],
  "qty": "",
  "qty2": ["", ""],
  "total_qty": "",
  "total": "",
  "mem": "10",
  "email_2": "",
  "ic_add": "890527-08-6136",
  "comm": "20",
  "grand": "",
  "cash": "120",
  "change": "120.00",
  "cust_id": "TGF 566",
  "cust_name": "coco crancy",
  "mem_id": "123",
  "mem_name": "QIZLAF MARKETING",
  "action": "test"
}
```

The above `json` is passed as `jQuery Object` via `ajax` to a page. And I use `foreach loop` to display values that has no array. For those with array values,I use `$.each loop` like below:

```
var _tableHTMl = "<table><thead><tr>"+
    "<th>Item Name</th>"+
    "<th>Unit Price RM</th>"+
    "<th>Qty</th>"+
    "<th>Amount</th></thead><tbody>";

$("#print_receipt").append(_tableHTML);


var new_array = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  new_array[i] = {
    'catalog_name': data[i].catalog_name,
    'price': data[i].price,
    'qty': data[i].qty,
    'amt': data[i].grand
  };

}
//this simply displays all values within one `<tr>` with comma separated

$.each(new_array, function(index, value) {
  $("#print_receipt").append(
    "<table><tr><td>" +
    value.catalog_name +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.price +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.qty +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.amt +
    "</td></tr></tbody></table>"
  );
});
```

The output:

[image]

RESULT  a per suggested by Rajesh:  
[image]

RESULT as per suggested by BG101:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: do you need a comma separated values or something else?? or different rows for each catalog name??

Comment: @Vanojx1, I need diff rows for each catalog name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve applied a split function to your data source , then i just given the json object to a datatable ( you can still use the append method ) .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var json = '[{"catalog_name": ["Sistem Autodownline ", "Karipap Pusing Ayu"],"price": ["100", "8"],"qty": "","qty2": ["", ""],"total_qty": "","total": "","mem": "10","email_2": "","ic_add": "890527-08-6136","comm": "20","grand": "","cash": "120","change": "120.00","cust_id": "TGF 566","cust_name": "coco crancy","mem_id": "123","mem_name": "QIZLAF MARKETING","action": "test"}]';
  
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  
  $.each(data,function(i,v){
    if($.isArray(v.catalog_name)){
      var newone = $.map(v.catalog_name,function(elem,j){
        return {catalog_name: elem, price: v.price[j], qty: v.qty, grand: v.grand }
      });
      Array.prototype.splice.apply(data,[i, newone.length].concat(newone));
    }
  });

  $('#table').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [{
      data: "catalog_name"
    }, {
      data: "price"
    }, {
      data: "qty"
    }, {
      data: "grand"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Unit Price RM</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Fabulous ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is causing issues,

```
$.each(new_array, function(index, value) {
  $("#print_receipt").append(
    "<table><tr><td>" +
    value.catalog_name +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.price +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.qty +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.amt +
    "</td></tr></tbody></table>"
  );
});
```

If you notice, you are adding `table` inside `table`.
Update it to this:

```
$.each(new_array, function(index, value) {
  $("#print_receipt").append(
    "<tr><td>" +
    value.catalog_name +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.price +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.qty +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.amt +
    "</td></tr>"
  );
});
```

#### Edit 1

As pointed out by @BG101, `print_receipt` is a container and not a `table`. So either you can add `ID` while creating table, or you can add table in `querySelector` like `$("#print_receipt table")`.

Also following is a working sample code:

```js
var data = [{
  "catalog_name": ["Sistem Autodownline ", "Karipap Pusing Ayu"],
  "price": ["100", "8"],
  "qty": "",
  "qty2": ["", ""],
  "total_qty": "",
  "total": "",
  "mem": "10",
  "email_2": "",
  "ic_add": "890527-08-6136",
  "comm": "20",
  "grand": "",
  "cash": "120",
  "change": "120.00",
  "cust_id": "TGF 566",
  "cust_name": "coco crancy",
  "mem_id": "123",
  "mem_name": "QIZLAF MARKETING",
  "action": "test"
}]

var _tableHTMl = "<table><thead><tr>" +
  "<th>Item Name</th>" +
  "<th>Unit Price RM</th>" +
  "<th>Qty</th>" +
  "<th>Amount</th></thead><tbody>";

$("#print_receipt").append(_tableHTMl);


var new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  new_array.push({
    'catalog_name': data[i].catalog_name,
    'price': data[i].price,
    'qty': data[i].qty,
    'amt': data[i].grand
  });

}

$.each(new_array, function(index, value) {
  $("#print_receipt table").append(
    "<tr><td>" +
    value.catalog_name +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.price +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.qty +
    "</td><td>" +
    value.amt +
    "</td></tr>"
  );
});
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="print_receipt" ></div>
```

Comment: `#print_receipt` is not the `table`, it is a container the `table` is appended to.

Comment: @Rajesh,  I tried your suggestion, please refer to my post above as I've added the result as per your code

Comment: @ BG101 Thanks for pointing it. Also @Karen I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Rajesh, but in your sample code, all data are displaying in a single row, they don't break to new lines?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is desired output? Do you want to split names into multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create another `<table>` tag but extend the `<tbody>`

```
$("#print_receipt").append(
"<table><tr><td>" +
value.catalog_name +
```

this will break the connection within the layout
it should be more like this:

```
$("#print_receipt").append(
"<tr><td>" +
```

... an don't forget the closing tags
for the multiple values (arrays) you could use `array.join('<concatenation character[s]')` which will transform them to a string.

or if you need to do special transformation where you want for example a list within a `<td>` you can use

`"<ul>" + array.map(function(item){ return "<li>" + item + "<li>"; }) + "</ul>"` or something like that

but the layout breaks because you're not extending the table with the `<th>` you're breaking it :).